# How to create a container with a sharp arrow on its edge in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a `Container`, which has a sharp triangle type figure or arrow on its edge, exactly like in the picture below. If there is a pre-defined widget for funtions like this, please do tell me.

[image]

Comment: you can try with the [super tooltip](https://pub.dev/packages/super_tooltip) or try with custom painter

Answer (score 0):

You can use CustomPainter,try this

```
 Container(
         child:Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
           crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.end,
         children:[
           
            Container(
            child:CustomPaint(
            painter: TrianglePainter(
              strokeColor: Colors.red,
              strokeWidth: 10,
              paintingStyle: PaintingStyle.fill,
            ),
            child: Container(
              height: 10,
              width: 20,
            ),
          )
          ),
           Container(
            color:Colors.red,
            height:2,
            width:100,
          ),
          Container(
            color:Colors.blue,
            height:20,
            width:100,
          )
         ]
         )
           
         )
```

Triangle Painter Class:

```
class TrianglePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Color strokeColor;
  final PaintingStyle paintingStyle;
  final double strokeWidth;

  TrianglePainter({this.strokeColor = Colors.black, this.strokeWidth = 3, this.paintingStyle = PaintingStyle.stroke});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = strokeColor
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..style = paintingStyle;

    canvas.drawPath(getTrianglePath(size.width, size.height), paint);
  }

  Path getTrianglePath(double x, double y) {
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(0, y)
      ..lineTo(x / 2, 0)
      ..lineTo(x, y)
      ..lineTo(0, y);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(TrianglePainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.strokeColor != strokeColor ||
        oldDelegate.paintingStyle != paintingStyle ||
        oldDelegate.strokeWidth != strokeWidth;
  }
}
```